# What is a simple way of using snakeyaml to parse this file into an object?

Tags: java, parsing, file-io, snakeyaml

Assume that I have a file that is of the following format that needs to be passed

```
Name: XYZ
 SSN: 123

Name: ABC
 SSN: 456
```

Assume I have created the following class

```
Class Data{
 String name;
 int ssn;
 }
```

Now I need to parse the above file and for each entry, I need to create an object of type data. How can I do it using snakeyaml in Java?

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, I could not get this to work with SnakeYaml but I could get it working with YamlBeans. Here's what the YAML document looks like (after fixing the errors from my previous answer):

```
-
  name: XYZ
  ssn: 123
-
  name: ABC
  ssn: 456
```

Here's the source:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;

import com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.YamlException;
import com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.YamlReader;

public class ArraySpike
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, YamlException
    {
        System.out.println("Parsing " + args[0] + " ...\n");

        YamlReader reader = new YamlReader(new FileReader(args[0]));

        Data[] dArray = reader.read(Data[].class);

        for (Data d: dArray)
        {
            System.out.println("name: " + d.name);
            System.out.println("ssn: " + d.ssn + "\n");
        }

    }
}
```

As per my previous comment, I changed the "Data" class into a proper bean.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to YAML and SnakeYaml myself, but the first thing I notice is that your "Class" class is not a Java Bean. You need to make getters and setters for "name" and "ssn". The second thing I notice is that the names of your class members and the information in your YAML document do not agree ("Name" vs. "name", "SSN" vs. "ssn"). Finally, the space before the "SSN" in your YAML document is going to cause problems.